# Panel/Label flickers with forecolor & background slows my form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

why does my panel/label flickers with BackColor & my form is laggy and flickering when i disable my label & panel. I already set DoubleBuffering to TRUE but it keeps on flickering. I realise that when i remove the image, it does not flicker because my panel & labels are not overlapped with the bnackground image. My image is 1920x698 resolution.

[image]

The code

````
 Private Sub FrmMain_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        createfolder("reports")
        FrmLogin.Hide()
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True


        AverageLandingPanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0)
        PopularDestinationPanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0)
        MostFlownAfctTxt.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0)
        TtlMilesTxt.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0)



        'UiFunctions.Startup()
        Try
            'DBFunctions.sendlogin()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
    ```
````

Comment: `DoubleBuffering to TRUE` on the form only makes the form DoubleBuffered, not the controls.  Show your code.

Comment: Hi, i believe theres one settings in the form for double buffering. In the form main_load, i did set Me.DoubleBuffered=true.

Comment: ok, but that doesn't change my statement.

Comment: Which part of the code would you like to see?

Comment: Minimal code that would duplicate it for us.

Comment: You may need a custom Panel, where you set some Styles (in the class constructor): `Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or ControlStyles.UserPaint Or ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)`. It also depends on how those Labels are drawn.

Comment: Hi guys, i updated with codes.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom panel with DoubleBuffering Enabled. In this example I put a table layout panel on the form and added the custom panel to col0 row0

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim _Panel As New CustomPanel
    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(_Panel, 0, 0)
End Sub

Public Class CustomPanel
    Inherits Panel

    Public Sub New()
        DoubleBuffered = True
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        BackColor = Color.Red
    End Sub

End Class
```